# Can you say "He is fluent in his native French and Mandarin"?

Tags: grammar

I know that this sentence is correct: "He is fluent in Swahili, besides being fluent in his native French".

Is it possible to say this with two languages though?

"He is fluent in Swahili, besides being fluent in his native French and Mandarin."

Thank you!

Comment: He is a fluent native speaker of both French and Mandarin.

Comment: Yes, someone can be fluent in both languages.  I would not write the sentence you propose, however, unless both French and Mandrin are the subject's native tongues.  If his only native tongue is French, then you might write: "He is fluent both in Mandrin and in his native French," or, "Along with being fluent in his native French, he is fluent in Mandrin."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - Yes the subject's native tongues are indeed French and Mandarin. I was just wondering if one can use the phrase "fluent in one's native" with two languages.
e.g. "He is fluent in his native French and Mandarin" instead of just "He is fluent in his native French".

Comment: Yes.  One could have a French mother and a Chinese father.  One could have Chinese parents and grown up in Paris, speaking Chinese at home and French at school.  There are endless possibilities for this.  Many, many people all over the world live where there are two native tongues: Wales (Welsh and English), Pamplona (Basque and Castilian Spanish), Quebec (French and English), India (Hindi and English)... Having more than one native language is not at all uncommon.

Comment: Yes, but it is ambiguous whether you mean (1) fluent in (a) his native French and (b) Chinese or (2) fluent in French and Chinese, both of which are (somehow) his native languages.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so, I think you can't be "native" in two languages. Native means that you were born at some place.

Comment: If you are a native of a multilingual community or household, you may have multiple native languages.

Comment: Native is just a description that can apply to multiple attributes of a person.  Being "a native of" and having "a native tongue" are different.  One may, in fact, have multiple native tongues. fMRI studies support this. :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroscience_of_multilingualism